# kendo grid change column name from model attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do I change the text that renders for my kendo grid column headers?  Is it possible to mark up my Model with attributes to accomplish this?

```
public class ConfigProject
{

    public ConfigTeam Team                      { get; set; }

    [Description("Project Name")]
    public string Name                          { get; set; }

    [Description("Project Description")]
    public string Description                   { get; set; }


    public List<ConfigSetting>      Settings      { get; set; }
}
```

So say I want Project Name and Project Description to render instead of the property names of Name and Description...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry never fails, found it moments after posting question.  The attribute i was looking for is called Display name.

```
    public class ConfigProject
{

    public ConfigTeam Team                      { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Project Name")]
    public string Name                          { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Project Description")]
    public string Description                   { get; set; }


    public List<ConfigSetting>      Settings      { get; set; }
}
```